# How to add a magnet URL to bittorrent programmatically from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, bittorrent

I have a database table where Magnet URLs are stored by another program, like magnet:?stuff.com%num. I would like to use a separate program to add these URLs to bittorrent.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If magnet links are already associated with BitTorrent you can simply use `Diagnostics.Process.Start`

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start("magnet:?...")
```

if magnet links are not associated then you can just pass the magnet link as a argument like so:

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\...\BitTorrent.exe", "magnet:?...")
```

Comment: I found this out after testing for a little while. But, thanks for the answer!